# Continuity Property Proof Check

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity

Suppose $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ and $f(x_0)>M$. I claim that $f(x)>M$ for all $x$ in some neighborhood of $x_0$. Let $M=f(x_1)$. We have that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x) > f(x_1)$. Suppose that $x_0>x_1$. Then choose $\epsilon >0$ such that $f(x_1)\not\in(f(x_0)-\epsilon,f(x_0)+\epsilon)$ and since $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ there exists $\delta >0$ such that $x_1\not\in(x_0-\epsilon,x_0+\epsilon)$. Therefore, for all $x\in(x_0-\delta,x_0+\delta)$ we have that $f(x)>f(x_1)=M$, as desired. The proof holds if $x_1 >x_0$.

Comment: Not a good start, there is not even a reason to assume there is an $x_1$ such that $f(x_1)=M$. Start like this. Let $f(x_0)=B\gt M$.

Comment: Why is that not a valid starting assumption? Bear in mind, this is for an introductory Real Analysis course that has not made mention of convergence, so I can't go about it from that perspective. I am limited to the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We only know that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$. We have no other knowledge about $f$. In particular it might be continuous only at $x=x_0$.

For a good start, suppose that $f(x_0)=B\gt M$. Let $\epsilon=\frac{B-M}{2}$. Now use the meaning of continuity at $x_0$.

**Added:** There is a $\delta\gt 0$ such that if $|x-x_0|\lt \delta$ then $|f(x)-B|\lt \epsilon=\frac{B-M}{2}$. Thus in the interval $x_0-\delta\lt x\lt x_0+\delta$ we have 
$$B-\frac{B-M}{2}\lt f(x)\lt B+\frac{B-M}{2}.$$
Only the first inequality matters.   Rewrite as
$$f(x)\gt B-\frac{B-M}{2}=\frac{B+M}{2}\gt M.$$

**Remark:** We have used inequalities in the traditional $\epsilon$-$\delta$ style. However, the geometry comes first, and a little sketch helps in figuring out what is going on. If $f(x_0)=B\gt M$, then for a while $f(x)$ stays close to $B$.

Comment: Okay, that gives that $|f(x)-B|<\frac{B-M}{2}$ if $|x-x_0|<\delta$. Do I need to somehow use the triangle inequality?

Comment: The Triangle Inequality is not needed. I will add to the post, since typing math in comments can be painful. A few minutes!

Comment: You are welcome.